# static / abstract conflict

Tags: java, static, abstract

I have an abstract class (AveragedDataRecord) which I need to abstract even further (DataRecord) so I can extend it to the original class and a new concrete class (SummedDataRecord) and I'm having problems getting some of the methods to translate from the original abstract class up to the new super class.

```
public abstract class DataRecord{
  protected abstract DataRecord getFirstRecord(ArrayList<T> dataList);
  protected abstract DataRecord getLastRecord(ArrayList<T> dataList);

  protected DateTime getFirstRecordTimestamp(ArrayList<T> dataList){
    DateTime result   = new DateTime(DEFAULT_DATETIME);
    DataRecord record = this.getFirstRecord(dataList);
    if(null != record)
      result = record.getRecordDateTime();
    return result;
  }

  protected DateTime getLastRecordTimestamp(ArrayList<T> dataList){
    DateTime result   = new DateTime(DEFAULT_DATETIME);
    DataRecord record = this.getLastRecord(dataList);
    if(null != record)
      result = record.getRecordDateTime();
    return result;
  }
}

public abstract class AveragedDataRecord extends DataRecord<AveragedDataRecord> {
  public AveragedDataRecord getFirstRecord(ArrayList<AveragedDataRecord> dataList){
    // Implementation
  }

  public AveragedDataRecord getLastRecord(ArrayList<AveragedDataRecord> dataList){
    // Implementation
  }

  public static void myMethod(ArrayList<AveragedDataRecord> dataList){
    // beginning of method code
    fileWriter.write(itemA, itemB, **getLatestTimestamp(dataList)**);
    // end of method code
  }
}
```

The issue that I am having is that the noted method call above shows an error.  The "quick fix" is suggesting that getLatestTimestamp() needs to be static.

Making getLatestTimestamp() static gives me an error on the declaration because Java "cannot make static reference to non-static type T".

I've chased this up and down the quick fixes and haven't found any mention of this particular problem in the forums I belong to nor on Google.  I can't believe I'm the only person this ever happened to but if the solution to this is out there, I haven't been fortunate enough to find it.

Comment: Why do you have two of the exact same methods in the sub-class?

Comment: where is getLatestTimestamp defined?

Comment: Is this your actual code? The keyword `class` is missing. Also, what is `T`? `DataRecord` doesn't have a type parameter.

Comment: @RamanSB - thanks for pointing out that I'd typed that incorrectly.

Comment: @PaulBoddington - this is not the actual code, as it is considerably more involved.  if providing the actual code would help, I can do that but it will take considerable time to obfuscate the code so it's readable but not putting proprietary info in a public forum.  also, thanks for pointing out the missing keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use getLatestTimeStamp() in a static context, i.e. with in a static method, then the getLatestTimeStamp() must be a static method, that is why the *quick-fix* suggests marking the getLatestTimeStamp method as static. On the other hand you can create an instance of the class in which the getLatestTimeStamp method is defined and then access the getLatestTimeStamp via that reference.

To use a non-static method in a static context, you must access the non-static method via a reference.

Remember, non-static fields cannot be used in a static context, except via the a reference.

---

Replace the **getLatestTimestamp(dataList)** in your code with the following:

```
    new /*/().getLatestTimestamp(dataList);

    // Replace /*/ with the name of the class in which getLatestTimestamp is created
```

Comment: as suggested by @PaulBoddington, I'm going get more of the code into myMethod() so that it's clearer what is actually going on.  this suggestion may end being or leading to the solution, and I will mark it so if and when I've implemented a solution from this information.